# Please help! Website isn't displaying correctly in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I recently designed a site in Drupal and it is perfect in FireFox and Safari, but wont' display correctly in IE6 or IE7.

The site might be NSFW, but it's just a Pickup Artist Website: 
http://bradp.com.

Could someone point me in the right direction of what to fix? I'd be very grateful.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: You'll probably get more responses if you can take down some of the NSFW content temporarily.  Then again, there are a lot of brave souls out there.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have two IFIE stylesheets. I would start by taking a look at thouse and make sure that any changes that you made to the main stylesheet aren't being over written by the IFIE ones. I would see what happens when you load the site without the conditional stylesheets. It may even be something as simple as your "clearfixes" not working right in IE.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As BrandonRandon indicated, in these situations, one thing that helps is to remove as much of the conditionals as possible; also simplify the page down to its most essential elements. Test that in IE and see if it works; if not, remove more stuff until you have something that works in IE. Now start adding elements one by one and testing at each step, until you get to the piece that breaks it. Then you can fix that problem object.

Good luck.